# SharePoint Online invites contain link to Legal site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I created a SP group which I am the owner of and added 2 users to it.  Since I'm the owner I got both invites but they have a link to our Legal SP site in them, not just info saying they are now members of XYZ group (which I just created).  Furthermore, SP automatically granted permissions to one of the users to the Legal site!

I checked the default groups for the Legal site and they are what they should be and not associated with the new group I created.

Where should I look to troubleshoot this more?  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can reproduce your issue.

It’s by default that the user grant access to the site, since the site is shared with the users when we add them to the group.

[image]

To not grant the site permission to these users, I recommend you not granting permissions to this group before join these users.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Question:
1. why does it pick that site if the group is a member of other sites?